# OData $select fails with missing property error

Tags: api, select, odata, serialization

I'm building an odata service that is used for reading from sql and then rendering the results in json format. I'm not using entityframework though.

When applying the $select filter, if I have less properties than my model (removing a nullable one), I'm getting the following error. If I have the exact same amount of properties, everything works fine.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'.",
      "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
      "stacktrace": "",
      "internalexception": {
        "message": "The EDM instance of type '[PrototypeOData.Models.DefaultRule Nullable=True]' is missing the property 'DateLastModified'.",
        "type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "stacktrace": "   at System.Web.OData.EntityInstanceContext.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateStructuralProperty(IEdmStructuralProperty structuralProperty, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateStructuralPropertyBag(IEnumerable`1 structuralProperties, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteEntry(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference feedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__14.MoveNext()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class DefaultRule
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? RequestedCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateLastModified { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller the calls are as follows:

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<DefaultRule> options)
        {
            .............
            var res = options.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(result, new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 100}).AsQueryable();
            //return result;
            return Ok(res, res.GetType());
        }

        private IHttpActionResult Ok(object content, Type type)
        {
            Type resultType = typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType, content, this) as IHttpActionResult;
        }
```

Is there any way I can mark specific properties as optional? 
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some examples of working and not worknig URLs please?

Comment: Yes. An example of a working URL is: http://localhost:35888/DefaultRule?$select=Id,RequestedCount,DateLastModified. An example of a non-working URL is http://localhost:35888/DefaultRule?$select=Id, RequestedCount

Answer (score 0):

This is because your the result of $select is not your original model. Then error occurs in Serialization. Try add the pagesize in attribute like:

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize=100)]
```

or create your own attribute

```
public class MyEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
          return options.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(result, new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 100}).AsQueryable().
    }
}

[MyEnableQueryAttribute]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    ....
    return result;
}
```